# Distributed build systems

Tags: linux, compiling, distributions, opensource-projects

Which tools for distributed builds are currently in use in popular Linux distros, like Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat, etc.?

For example, we have a huge amount of packages with dependencies and try to compile all of them for the new release of the distro. It takes a lot of time to build them one by one. I have heard about distcc, but it shares one project compilation between the servers for distributed parallel building.

Is there any tool which analyzes dependencies between the packages (creates a graph, for example) and creates a schedule for building with package-level parallelism? For example, we have packages p1, p2, p3, p4, and two servers. One server builds p1, another p2 at the same time if they are not dependent on each other.

I need examples of the projects which are being used in production.

Comment: Most modern distros deliver pre-compiled packages. Unless I mis-understand your question, it sounds like you are compiling most of the software for your systems locally. Is this correct? If not, what distro(s) are you using?

Comment: I build packages for custom Debian-like distro. Sometimes I need to rebuild the whole set of packages from sources. The result is a set of .deb packages with binaries inside. But it is a long-running process, so I am interested in ways of solving this problem.

Comment: Sounds awesome. And challenging. Thanks for the info, I see Stephen has already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each distribution tends to have its own set of tools for this, there’s not much shared software here.

Debian uses `wanna-build`, `buildd` and `sbuild`, which you’ll all find documented [on the Debian site](https://www.debian.org/devel/buildd/) (follow the links too). `wanna-build` maintains the build queue, `buildd` picks a package to build, and `sbuild` builds it. `wanna-build` tracks packages with missing dependencies using [the “dep-wait” state](https://www.debian.org/devel/buildd/wanna-build-states); packages can enter that state directly (if `wanna-build` itself can identify that dependencies are missing) or after a build fails because of missing dependencies. There’s a [tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianWannaBuildInfrastructureOnOneServer) available if you want to set up a local build infrastructure.

Fedora uses [Koji](https://pagure.io/koji/), which is [extensively documented](https://docs.pagure.org/koji/). It also [involves a number of different components](https://docs.pagure.org/koji/HOWTO/#koji-components), including `koji-hub`, the centralised database front-end, and `kojid` , which drives the builds. I’m not as familiar with Koji though so I don’t know how it all integrates to handle build states.

Other distributions have other build systems, such as [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). They all handle the same concerns you have: a centralised view of all the packages, multiple build systems, and a centralised repository which receives the build results.